# Question regarding Spark sql tables and databases

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and am confused regarding the below point:

When we are creating new databases and global tables for our own analysis(using dataframe API or spark sql), where are these getting created/stored? Are these getting stored in Spark memory or in external storage(could be Hive/HDFS/RDBMS..etc) from where Spark is reading data? Does temporary view/local tables only get created in Spark memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> When we are creating new databases and global tables for our own analysis(using dataframe API or spark sql), where are these getting created/stored?

It depends on your infrastructure. For example:

- If you're in an on-prem environment, the underlying data is on HDFS
- If you're in Azure Databricks, the underlying data is on Azure Data Storage
- If you're in Databricks Cloud, the underlying data is on Amazon S3

> Are these getting stored in Spark memory or in external storage(could be Hive/HDFS/RDBMS..etc) from where Spark is reading data?

This data only loaded to memory when you call `df.cache()`

> Does temporary view/local tables only get created in Spark memory?

Yes